# Select input changes the values of second select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello I have first one input which is

```
<select id="selectcontract" name="contract" class="input-xlarge" >
<option value="">Contract</option>
<option value="1">Buy</option>
<option value="2">Rent</option>
```

this input contains 2 options Buy and Rent. So I would like when you choose Buy foe example to populate the values of second and third input if you choose Rent to populate exactly those same inputs but with different values and value names.

here are the second and the third inputs:

**Second Select:**

```
<select id="Pricefrom" name="minimum_price" >
    <option value="">Price From</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="500">500</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="1500">1500</option>
```

**Third Select:**

```
<select id="Princeuntil" name="maximum_price" >
    <option value="">Price Until</option>
    <option value="500">500</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="1500">1500</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
```

Any advice in which direction I should realize this goal ? I guess it should be something with jquery since the change should be made mediate when you choose either buy or rent.

Comment: could be done in pure javascript (and hardcoded lists), could be done with ajax (hitting the server to get the list, maybe search a database)...depends on what you want to do..too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one div for buy and one for rent with class and after show or hide their
Example on fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tehb2fxt/1/

Div Buy (is necessary change the name prop to not repeat) and add CLASS "class_price"

```
<select id="selectcontract" name="contract" class="input-xlarge class_price">    
<option value="">Contract</option>
<option value="1">Buy</option>
<option value="2">Rent</option> 
</select>
<div class="div_buy" style="display: none">
    <select id="Pricefrom_buy" name="Pricefrom_buy" class="class_price">
    <option value="">Price From Buy</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="500">500</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="1500">1500</option>
</select>     
     <select id="Princeuntil_buy" name="Princeuntil_buy" class="class_price">
    <option value="">Price Until Buy</option>
    <option value="500">500</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="1500">1500</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="div_rent" style="display: none">
    <select id="Pricefrom_rent" name="Pricefrom_rent" class="class_price">
    <option value="">Price From Rent</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="800">800</option>
    <option value="8000">8000</option>
    <option value="8500">8500</option>
</select>     
     <select id="Princeuntil_rent" name="Princeuntil_rent" class="class_price">
    <option value="">Price Until Rent</option>
    <option value="900">900</option>
    <option value="9000">9000</option>
    <option value="9500">9500</option>
    <option value="9000">9000</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Jquery to show and hide according with select:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#selectcontract').change
            (
                function() 
                {
                    if($(this).val() == "1")
                    {
                        $('.div_buy').show('slow');
                        $('.div_rent').hide('slow');
                    }
                    else if($(this).val() == "2")
                    {
                        $('.div_buy').hide('slow');
                        $('.div_rent').show('slow');
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $('.div_buy').hide('slow');
                        $('.div_rent').hide('slow');
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
 </script>
```

To control and not be in conflict 2 selects add input text(will changed to type="hidden" when finish test) for recovery values of pricefrom and princeuntil(buy and rent)

```
<input type="hidden" id="Pricefrom" value="0" name="Pricefrom">
<input type="hidden" id="Princeuntil" value="0" name="Princeuntil">
```

And add event Jquery when values class changed

```
$('.class_price').change
            (
                function () {
                if($('#selectcontract').val() == "1") //if buy
                    {
                        $('#Pricefrom').val($('#Pricefrom_buy').val()); //get value select
                        $('#Princeuntil').val($('#Princeuntil_buy').val()); //get value select

                    }
                    else if($('#selectcontract').val() == "2") //if rent
                    {
                        $('#Pricefrom').val($('#Pricefrom_rent').val()); //get value select
                        $('#Princeuntil').val($('#Princeuntil_rent').val()); //get value select
                    }
                    else {//if not select
                    $('#Pricefrom').val("0"); 
                    $('#Princeuntil').val("0");
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: This looks like a good elegant decision. in this case If I have 2 select elements with the same name will that be in conflict with the submit form ?

Comment: Yes it is necessary to treat them at the time of submit. You can check with the Php or with jQuery verify which option was selected. I will make a basic example via jquery, and in an instant update the code.

Comment: Can verify @JohnSiniger ?

Comment: ok thanks, I have used it now just have to select which select is available for the form to submit.

Comment: Cool, this function is run on submit if can help $("form").on("submit", function () {
                //function
            });

Comment: Thats good, not at all!

Answer (score 0):

## Static Lists

A simple fiddle proof of concept.

https://jsfiddle.net/cgjjg2dy/

The main part is:

```
$('#selectcontract').change(function (event) {
    $(".section").hide();
    $("#section" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

I hide all the sections, then I show the one that corresponds to the option chosen. You can get even fancier with `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` too!

## AJAX

If you want to dynamically retrieve your options from a server/database, you have to use AJAX. Instead of using `.hide()` and `.show()` in your `change()` handler, you just make an AJAX call and retrieve the data, then modify the DOM as necessary. Quite a bit more complex, but still the same idea.